# Add Cocoapods in Swift <unknown>:0: error:

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I'm trying to add cocoapods in swift. I added a header file in "Build Settings"--> Objective-C Bridging Header -- > ProjectName/ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h

THEN In ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h

import ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa.h  and import Mantle/Mantle.h

When building it, the error was showing like this :
:0: error: /Users/.../Pods/Headers/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/RACSignal+Operations.h:640: expected selector for Objective-C method
:0: error: :0: error: /Users/.../Pods/Headers/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/RACSignal+Operations.h:647: expected selector for Objective-C method
:0: error: /Users/.../Pods/Headers/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/RACSignal+Operations.h:654: expected selector for Objective-C method
:0: error: /Users/...//Pods/Headers/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/RACSignal+Operations.h:640: expected selector for Objective-C method
:0: error: /Users/.../Pods/Headers/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/RACSignal+Operations.h:647: expected selector for Objective-C method
:0: error: /Users/.../Pods/Headers/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/RACSignal+Operations.h:654: expected selector for Objective-C method
:0: error: /Users/.../Pods/Headers/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/RACSignal+Operations.h:640: expected selector for Objective-C method
:0: error: /Users/.../Pods/Headers/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/RACSignal+Operations.h:647: expected selector for Objective-C method
:0: error: /Users/.../Pods/Headers/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/RACSignal+Operations.h:654: expected selector for Objective-C method

Comment: A friend was told in the WWDC labs that the problem is actually caused by the preprocessor and it should be fixable by `#undef or`, `#undef and` & `#undef not`. Unfortunately this didn't work for me. :(

Comment: Thank you for the answer ( : yah... I tried this way too, it didn't work for me either.

Answer (score 1):

It occurs that compiler generates error, when it sees methods named and, or, not. Three of them actually exists, exactly where compiler points out, in the RACSignal+Operations.h file at lines number 640, 647, 654.

Everything you need is rename those method using refactor tool. For example you can add a prefix rac_, so I will have rac_and, rac_or, rac_not. Just find those method in the RACSignal+Operations.h, select right-click and select refactor-rename.

Also, I strongly recommend to read this post about ReactiveCocoa and Swift: [A Swift Reaction](http://napora.org/a-swift-reaction/)

Comment: Also none of those words actually are reserved words, and probably it is a compiler bug, which will be fixed in the future.